# Aggregation $graphLookup retrieving results in different order every-time the query is executed?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, graphlookup

I have the following dataset (categories):

```
[{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "Root",
  "parent": null
},
 {
   "_id": 2,
   "name": "Sub - Level 1",
   "parent": 1
 }, {
   "_id": 3,
   "name": "Sub - Level 2",
   "parent": 2
 }, {
   "_id": 4,
   "name": "Sub - Level 3",
   "parent": 3
 }
]
```

and I am running the following pipeline on this dataset to fetch the tree recursively:

```
[{
  '$match': {
    '_id': 1
  }
}, {
  '$graphLookup': {
    'from': 'categories', 
    'startWith': '$_id', 
    'connectFromField': '_id', 
    'connectToField': 'parent', 
    'as': 'menu'
  }
}, {
    '$sort': {
      'menu.parent': 1
    }
  }]
```

The aim is to fetch the tree recursively like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Root",
    "parent: "null",
    "menu": [
        {..sub},{..sub},{...sub}
    ]
}
```

It does the job, but each time the query is executed the order of the elements in the `menu` array is different. EVERYTIME!

```
"menu" : [{... Sub - Level 2},{... Sub - Level 3}, {... Sub - Level 1}]
"menu" : [{... Sub - Level 1},{... Sub - Level 3}, {... Sub - Level 2}]
"menu" : [{... Sub - Level 3},{... Sub - Level 1}, {... Sub - Level 2}]
```

Is this the normal behaviour of `$graphLookup` or am I missing out on something? How am I supposed to sort the `menu` array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Documents returned in the as field **are not guaranteed to be in any order**.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#definition

> If you need an order, consider specifying the 'depthField' argument, and sorting by that.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26153

**Workaround:**

```
db.categories.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "parent",
      "as": "menu",
      depthField: "order"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$menu"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1,
      "menu.order": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      parent: {
        $first: "$parent"
      },
      menu: {
        $push: "$menu"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "menu.order" //Change to $project:{"menu.order":0} for MongoDB <v4.2
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8y9P8qpZZVg)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I just have one question, would it be better to use my pipeline and sort the menu array in JS rather than using these extra pipelines? What according to you would be faster and cost effective?

Comment: @saibbyweb for small amount of data, JS / BSON order has the same performance. For huge dataset, BSON will have better performance

Comment: Got to learn a lot from your answer. Thanks again, have a great day ahead.

Comment: This is understated in docs imo @Valijon life saver